# symfony 4 Doctrine service allowed memory size exhausted

Tags: service, doctrine-orm

I inject '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager' in a simple class service like this:

```
tigris_base.array_to_form:
    class: Tigris\BaseBundle\Service\ArrayToFormService
    arguments: ['@form.factory', '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']
    public: true
```

And my service constructor

```
public function __construct(FormFactory $formFactory, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
{
    $this->formFactory = $formFactory;
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
}
```

But I have an error:

> Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes)

I try to set a higher value in PHP.ini.
I don't understand why I have this error, I use doctrine services in other services and it works.

Do you know where is the problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of that by any chance?

Comment: @Loïc Ovigne did you manage to find a solution ?